# Best pattern for reading a FileItem object

Tags: java, file-io

I am using the Apache Commons Uploader package, and I am trying to read a file that is being uploaded. I have a FileItem object.

The first few lines of the file are ASCII and I want to be able to read them and extract the metadata that is contained in them. What is the best method/pattern to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Call `getInputStream()` on the `FileItem`, wrap that in a `BufferedReader`, then read your file line by line using `BufferedReader.readLine()` until you've read the meta data.

Answer (score 1):

```
        final List<FileItem> files = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
                .parseRequest(httpRequest.getWrappedRequest());
        final List<Long> images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final FileItem file : files) {
            if (file.getFieldName().equals("file")) {
                final InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();
                final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);

                ...
                file.delete();
            }
        }
        files.clear();
```